# Using Java/Selenium - How many animations are running

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors

I want to find out how many animations are running at a website. But my selenium code throws an InvalidSelectorException.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(":animated")).length()
```

How do I get correctly the amount of running animations in Java/Selenium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pseudo class `:animated` is specific to the JQuery library and is not a valid CSS selector.

If you wish to use it, then make sure that the page loads JQuery and execute the code with `executeScript`:

```
int count = (int)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "return $(':animated').length;");
```

Comment: I just ran across this blog talking about this very method with some twists... http://seanglover.com/blog/2012/04/wait-using-selenium-web-driver-with-jquery-animations/